# Graph cycles from vertex and degrees

Tags: graph-theory

Show that if every vertex in a graph has degree greater than one, then the graph contains a cycle. 
Is the converse true?

Comment: Similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387792/prove-that-every-undirected-finite-graph-with-vertex-degree-of-at-least-2-has-a?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

1. The converse is false, since you can take a cycle and add a pendant vertex whose degree is one.
2. The original statement is false, without the restriction that the graph is finite.
3. With that restriction, you can trace your finger from vertex to vertex.  You'll always be able to leave, since all degrees are greater than one.  With the graph being finite, eventually you'll have to repeat, and then you have a cycle.