# Are there counting techniques to count number of non-isomorphic graphs with six vertices, two of degree $4$ and four of degree $3$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

There is a question in the book "Discrete Mathematics and Applications" by Susanna Epp in the exercise set $10.4$ :

> $20.$ Draw four nonisomorphic graphs with six vertices, two of
>   degree $4$ and four of degree $3$.

[**Note :** By Graphs we mean undirected graphs where multiple edges and loops are allowed.]

I used handshaking theorem to find number of edges.

$\therefore 2(\text{Number of edges})=(4+4+3+3+3+3) \implies (\text{Number of edges})=10.$

I drew four non-isomorphic graphs as asked as follows :
[image]

After drawing them I found a fifth one as well:

[image]

Perhaps there are two more that I found out later.
[image]

Which led me to think whether there are counting techniques to count total number of non-isomorphic graphs for this problem?

**EDIT :** Like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2490502/206726) post of mine, aren't there any smooth ways? In that post I took cases having one circuit, two circuit,...etc which made it simple to count all the non-isomorphic graphs.

Comment: See here: http://oeis.org/A000088

Comment: ii, iv, vi and vii are not graphs as a graph is normally defined because they have multiple edges between the same nodes.

Comment: @Qudit see my edit with a note added.

Comment: @Math1000 I've been referred to this website before. Will have a look at it.