# Given some k, is it possible to make a connected undirected graph G with vertex degree k, such that at least one edge in G is a bridge?

Tags: graph-theory

I know that an edge is a bridge if it does not lie on a cycle. This [Math Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387792/prove-that-every-undirected-finite-graph-with-vertex-degree-of-at-least-2-has-a) link tells me that any graph with vertex degree $(k)$ greater than $2$ has a cycle.

So, I thought that no graph exists for $k >=2$ which has a bridge, but it turns out I am wrong. Could someone explain this to me, and tell me how I could generate such a graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following graph

[image]

One thing is that it contains a cycle and another thing is that every edge is in a cycle.

Comment: But the vertex degrees are not the same...

Comment: You are not specifying the regularity of the graph in the question. I am going to change it.